# automatically scroll to div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a sidebar div that auto loads new messages and Im trying to have the div automatically scroll to the last message posted. here is the html

```
<div class="row">   
  <div class="column col-sm-4" id="sidebar">
    <div class="message-wrap col-lg-12 col-md-6">
        <div class="msg-wrap" id="msg-wrap">
           <!-- start message loop -->
            <div class="media msg">
                <div class="media-body">
                     <small class="pull-right time"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> 12:12:12pm</small>
                      <a class="pull-left" href="#">
                         <div class="thumbnail" style="margin:5px;"> {pic} </div>
                      </a>
                      <strong class="media-heading">Guy Faux</strong>
                      <small class="col-lg-9">Hi this is Guy and im typing a message about Fauxing</small>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- end message loop -->

            <!-- start message loop -->
            <div class="media msg">
                <div class="media-body">
                     <small class="pull-right time"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> 12:12:12pm</small>
                      <a class="pull-left" href="#">
                         <div class="thumbnail" style="margin:5px;"> {pic} </div>
                      </a>
                      <strong class="media-heading">Guy Faux</strong>
                      <small class="col-lg-9">Hi this is Guy and im typing a message about Fauxing</small>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- end message loop -->

            <!-- start message loop -->
            <div class="media msg">
                <div class="media-body">
                     <small class="pull-right time"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> 12:12:12pm</small>
                      <a class="pull-left" href="#">
                         <div class="thumbnail" style="margin:5px;"> {pic} </div>
                      </a>
                      <strong class="media-heading">Guy Faux</strong>
                      <small class="col-lg-9">Hi this is Guy and im typing a message about Fauxing</small>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- end message loop -->

            <!-- start message loop -->
            <div class="media msg">
                <div class="media-body">
                     <small class="pull-right time"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> 12:12:12pm</small>
                      <a class="pull-left" href="#">
                         <div class="thumbnail" style="margin:5px;"> {pic} </div>
                      </a>
                      <strong class="media-heading">Guy Faux</strong>
                      <small class="col-lg-9">Hi this is Guy and im typing a message about Fauxing</small>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- end message loop -->
        </div>    
    </div>
</div>
```

I have tried this Js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var lastMsg = $('#msg-wrap .msg:last')

  var scrollToElement = function(el, ms){
   var speed = (ms) ? ms : 600;
   $('html,body').animate({
     scrollTop: $(el).offset().top
   }, speed);
 }  
 scrollToElement(lastMsg, 600);

});
```

I  Also tried several different lines of code I've searched on Stack :

`window.location.hash = lastMsg;`

`$('#msg-wrap .msg:last').focus();`

`$('#msg-wrap').animate({ scrollTop: lastMsg.offset().top }, 'fast');`

`$('html, body').animate({scrollTop:lastMsg.position().top}, 'slow');`

No matter what I try, nothing seems to work.  Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 4):

I made 2 small changes to your code, which can be found in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gunderson/q6mryLc1/4/) to be working:

```
var scrollToElement = function($el, ms){ 
    var speed = (ms) ? ms : 600;
    $('body').animate({ // only scroll the body element, the html element doesn't need to be scrolled at the same time
        scrollTop: $el.offset().top // you're already passing a jquery object, no need to re-wrap it
    }, speed);
}
```

Comment: Would it matter that I have other Divs wrapped around this. The code I've showed is just a side panel.  I clearly see it work in your code, its just not working in my system.

Comment: You can scroll any div. You just need to set the `height` and `overflow: scroll` styles. You may also need to subtract the `postion().top` of the wrapper from the msg position().top to get the correct `scrollTop` value to scroll to.

Comment: You need to include the `HTML` element in the selector - this is because different browsers won't scroll the body, and some won't scroll the HTML. It will also depend upon if you have height set to 100% on the element you are scrolling. It will need to be `height:auto`.

Answer (score 0):

I was playing around with the code Patrick gave me.  Figured it out with this code.

```
var scrollToElement = function($el, ms){ 
    var speed = (ms) ? ms : 600;
    $('.message-wrap').animate({ 
        scrollTop: $el.offset().top 
    }, speed);    
}

scrollToElement(lastMsg, 600);
```